# How to set test build type to current build type in gradle kotlin dsl?

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

So basically I'm figuring out how I can set testBuildType to the currently selected build variant. `testBuildType = "currentBuildType"` in Gradle using Kotlin DSL. I have custom build types in my project basically and I want the androidTest to be configured with the current build type.